# CMake - how to ignore standard include paths?

Tags: cmake, build-system

I need to use cusom-builded version of sodium library in my project. In parallel another version of this library already installed on my system ,as standard package (libsodium-dev)

So when I'm trying to find path to sodium headers/libraries - cmake still return standard paths, instead of my custom (paths correct, files - present)

```
find_path(SODIUM_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES sodium.h
        PATH_SUFFIXES  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/.libs/sodium/include)

if (SODIUM_INCLUDE_DIR)
    message (STATUS "Sodium include path: : ${SODIUM_INCLUDE_DIR}")
endif ()
```

->

```
 Sodium include path: : /usr/include
```

Please hint me  where I'm wrong.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: What you have in *PATH_SUFFIXES* option should actually be passed via *PATHS* option.

Comment: My mistake is to  take  "SODIUM_INCLUDE_DIR" name to find_library variable . Because later find_package_handle_standard_args somehow rewrite value. Once I'm used another name (SODIUM_CUSTOM_DIR) all works as expected. Anyway thanks to Tsyvarev  for hint.

This question is not an duplicate, sorry .

Comment: `Because later find_package_handle_standard_args somehow rewrite value.` - Strange, `find_package_handle_standard_args` shouldn't set a variable except `*_FOUND` one. If the question is not a duplicate, then it is a "problem can no longer be reproduced or simple typographical error" - another close reason for a question. If you feel that it is your case, then simply delete the question: your problem has been resolved in a manner which very unlikely helps the future readers (you don't show call to `find_package_handle_standard_args`, which may cause a conflict).

Comment: If you think your question may help to other readers, [edit] the question to the helpful state. (The best way is to include [mcve]). After the appropriate edit will be done, Stack Overflow community may reopen the question.